# SQLAlchemy: How to use variables in a update statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use a variable for a key inside a update statement, but it seems, that using variables is not allowed.

There is table "disamb":

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+  
| id | entity_a  | id_of_entity_a     | entity_b  | id_of_entity       |  
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+  
| 0  | table     |                    | bar       | -                  |  
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

And a table "entities":

```
+--------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+  
| entity | id |                           paraphrase                            |  
+--------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+  
| table  |  1 | An item of furniture with a flat top and one or more legs       |  
| table  |  2 | A data arrangement with rows and columns                        |  
| bar    |  3 | A retail business establishment that serves alcoholic beverages |  
| bar    |  4 | a long item                                                     |  
+--------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My program loops over the columns "entity_a" and "entity_b" in table "disamb" and searches in table "entities" for the corresponding words, ask me which to choose and then (should) writes it to the corresponding column "id_of_entity_a" resp. "id_of_entity_b".

So at one point of the loop the variables have for example this values:

```py
column_name = "id_of_entity_a"  
id_of_entity = "1"  
row = "0"
```

and I try to execute this code:

```
update_stmt = tbl.update().\
    values(column_name=id_of_entity).\
    where(tbl.columns.id == (row))
conn_mysql.execute(update_stmt)
```

It throws the error: "sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names: column_name"

How do I solves this problem? Thx!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I have a similar one.